# Is there any possibility to find the LU decomposition for only smallest pivot using Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to solve a linear system (Ax=b) of equations at each iteration of a nonlinear solver. I need information about incomplete LU of A, only for the smallest pivot in U, if L has unit diagonal entries. My program is written in Matlab.

I can do full LU and find corresponding L and U vectors for the smallest pivot, but it is costly as the matrix dimension is very large.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29358485/2531987) code helpful. I'm not entirely sure what is it that you're looking for, but if you just want to use the smallest values form each column of `A` as pivots, you can just change `max` to `min` on line 13 of the code above.