# cant find my code error in LU decomposition

Tags: matlab

i wrote this code to determine my l and u for the given matrix,but when i calculate l*u some arrays in its last column isn't the same as given matrix,it has messed up my mind...i appreciate your helps to make my code work.

```
clear
clc
a=[0 3 -4 2;2 6 4 -3;-1 -1 2 3;3 0 0 -5];
c=[26;9;7;-19];
n=length(a);
for k=1:n;
    pivot=k;
    big=abs(a(k,k));
    for i=(k+1):n;
        if a(i,k)>big;
            big=a(i,k);
            pivot=i;
        end
    end
if pivot~=k;
    a([pivot,k],:)=a([k,pivot],:);
end
end
for i=1:n;
    l(i,1)=a(i,1);
end
for i=1:n;
    u(i,i)=1;
end
for j=2:n;
    u(1,j)=a(1,j)/l(1,1);
end
for j=2:(n-1);
    for i=j:n;
        sum=a(i,j);
        for k=1:(j-1);
        sum=sum-l(i,k)*u(k,j);
        end
        l(i,j)=sum;
    end
    for k=(j+1):n;
        sum1=a(j,k);
        for i=1:(j-1);
        sum1=sum1-l(j,i)*a(i,k);
        end
        u(j,k)=sum1/l(j,j);
    end
end
for j=1:n;
    sum2=a(j,j);
    for k=1:(n-1);
        sum2=sum2-l(j,k)*a(k,j);
    end
    l(j,j)=sum2;
end
```

[image]

Comment: What does `for j=n` supposed to do? That is a single value always. Why a `for`?

Comment: @AnderBiguri it's 1:n , corrected it

Comment: Have you cheked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15304012/lu-decomposition-with-partial-pivoting-matlab

Comment: @AnderBiguri thats about pivoting only... Actually since i just took the numerical analysis course this semester,i'm not so good in matlab,and i cant find where's my code error.

Comment: Well, obviously this is for homework, as no one would program LU by themselves if its not for learning. What do you mean its only for pivoting? It creates good L and U matrices. If you want another method, you shoudl specify

Comment: @AnderBiguri i meant the link you gave me,it was just about pivoting.

Comment: I understood you were talking about the link..... But that code returns L and U, so its not only pivoting, its LU decomposition using pivoting.

Comment: @AnderBiguri oh yeah sorry,you know actually i found more better and more compact codes in the internet for LU and they work,but really i'm not interested in getting ideas by seeing someone else code,making my code work actually makes me feel better...

Comment: MY point: there are tons of code around. If you want to make your code work, then compare yourself with that, instead of asking a question, as there are so many codes that some of it has to be similar to yours.